# Function works only with hard coded values

Tags: java

This is the code I am working on:

```
if(connection.doDatabaseRead(findSQL))
  {
      ResultSet retRES = connection.getResultSet();

      int i = 0;

      // did we find anything
      while( retRES.next() )
      {        
          //read result from query
          suiteNum.add(retRES.getString(i)); // this is the problem 

          i++;

          //let other threads breathe
          Thread.yield();   
      }   
  }
```

`suiteNum` is a string vector

When I try to add the database results to the vector the code crashes with this error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 0 > 1.
```

I have the same piece of code working elsewhere in the program but I use real numbers like 0, 1 and 2 instead of i and it works fine.

As I do not know how many results the database request will have I need it to be dynamic but it will only work hard coded. 
How can I make it work with i ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument to [`getString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29) is the **column index**, not the **row index** as you seem to think. The function returns the value of the given column in the *current row*, while `next` advances the cursor to the next row.

You probably mean:

```
suiteNum.add(retRES.getString(1));
```

in which case you can lose `i` altogether.

Comment: but then how do I get multiple results from retRES ?

Comment: @Skeith: multiple rows or multiple columns?

Comment: I am expecting three strings to be returned from the database, 108, 109, 110 but using your suggestion I now get 110 three times in my vector. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Skeith: I suspect the problem is somewhere else. Can you print out the values of `retRES.getString(i)` as you get them (before you put them into `suiteNum`)?

Comment: Are the results returned as rows or columns?  If they are columns, add a for loop around the getString(i) line and increment i in it.  You can retRES.getResultSetMetadata() to get an object that will detail the number of columns in the result set. (handy for the for loop exit check)

Answer (score 1):

Java `ResultSet` objects are 1-indexed in this regard. The first element is at 1, not 0. See the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29).

EDIT: That's true too, but indeed the problem is this appears to be used as a row index! it's certainly the column.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
i = 0;
...
retRES.getString(i);
```

ResultSet.getString(i) gets a String from column number i

You want something like

```
while(retRes.next()) {
   add(retRes.getString(1);
}
```

Comment: i tried that and now i am getting the last result three times instead of the three different results, how do i solve that

Comment: What does your query look like? Sounds like very odd that you get the same result repeated... retRes.next() moves the cursor to the next unread row, and retRes.getString(some number) reads the value of column number "some number" on the current row.

Comment: findSQL = "SELECT area_id"+
                 " FROM suite_area" +      
                 " WHERE suite_id ='"+suiteName+"'"+
                 " AND area_id !='"+room+"'";

Answer (score 0):

column index starts from `1`

> As I do not know how many results the database request will have I need it to be dynamic but it will only work hard coded. How can I make it work with i

```
ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
```

**See Also**

- [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let your `i` start with 1 as specified [in the API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(connection.doDatabaseRead(findSQL))
                   {
                       ResultSet retRES = connection.getResultSet();

                       int i = 1;



               // did we find anything
                   while( retRES.next() )
                   {        
                       //read result from query
                       suiteNum.add(retRES.getString(i)); // this is the problem 

                       i++;

                       //let other threads breathe
                       Thread.yield();   
                   }   
               }
```